# How to hide null values during render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this API endpoint:

```
GET https://xxx/xx
```

Result:

```
{
    "name": "Ana",
    "status": null,
}
```

I render the API result inside a blank page in my App and the page contains the following:

```
Ana
null
```

I want to hide **null** values.I don't want 'null' to be shown at all. How can I achieve this in React/Javascript?

```
{name && (
                <span>
                  {name}
                  <br />
                </span>
              )}
{status && (
                <span>
                  {status}
                </span>
              )}
```

Comment: Change it to `{status ? (...) : null}` and do the same for name

Comment: actually status && () should work fine

Comment: @LucjanGrzesik, when the page is rendered for the first time, null appears. When I render it again, it disappears. I don't want to show it at all.

Comment: I think that when the page is rendered the first time you must have some default value for status that is a string.

Comment: @LucjanGrzesik `const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");`

Answer (score 0):

your code should work fine , I think you need to convert your api response to json.

Exemple

```
const response = await fetch(URL);
const jsonResponse = await response.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct from what you have told me in the comments I think that you have some default value set for the response that status is a string. Please verify it.

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<string | null>(null);
{status && (
                <span>
                  {status}
                </span>
              )}
```

when you are setting it with setStatus make sure that the value is not null like this

```
if (response.data.status) {
  setStatus(response.data.status)
}
```

Comment: The initial value is `const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");`

Comment: @Ani check my response

Comment: `if (response.data.status) {
  setStatus(response.data.status)
}` I think that this condition doesn't work correctly. I will add many functionalities in my app, one of those will be a form for updating name and status. If status is different from null, it will be shown in my app. If status is null, it will not be updated in the app (we won't have a setStatus) but it will show the old value. This is not correct, isn't it? Please let me know if I understand it in the wrong way.